# What does "LLP" stand for in the name of an organization?

Tags: small-business, financial-literacy, limited-liability-company

What does LLP stand for? As in the example name "Flood Law Group, LLP".

Comment: Limited Liability Partnership

Answer (score 6):

It means **Limited liability partnership**.

Limited liability means that the liabilities of the company (debts) can't be transferred to the partner(s) who has/have limited liability of the company.

If the company can't repay its debts, the partner(s) with limited liability can inject capital in the company, but do not have any obligations to do so.

You can find more information in the Wikipedia article at:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limited_liability_partnership

Comment: This is all true and correct, just wanted to add that an LLP does not provide partners a total shield from liability; in most other forms of limited-liability business entities, a person working in the course and scope of business of that entity is treated as an "agent" of the entity and is shielded from personal liability. An LLP, however, removes the "agency" relationship; a partner sued for fraud, misfeasance, negligence, malpractice etc is personally liable for any damages and cannot hide behind the partnership's shield. Only creditor debts and liability for others' actions is limited.